# Can't connect to port on google's android emulator running Oreo

Tags: android, emulation, android-8.0-oreo

I can connect to the android emulator running **Kitkat**, but this same process fails to connect when I switch the emulator to **Oreo**.

The error I get is: "The connection was reset".

My process is to start the emulator which is listening on port 8080.
I then run telnet and issue the command to connect to the localhost port 5554.  This works.  I find and enter the auth code as instructed.

Then issue the command "**redir add tcp:8090:8080**" which works.

Running **netstat** on my workstation shows the emulator process is listening on port 8090.  Then I try to connect to port 8090 using Firefox and get the connection reset error.

Please note that this same process works fine when I rerun the emulator running **Kitkat**.

A little more info: I'm running a non secured web server within the android emulator.  Is this the problem?  Does **Oreo** require me to run a secured server?

**added more info:
After re reading the post I realized I neglected to mention that I can connect to the port within the emulator but not from outside.  I can confirm, using the debugger, that the post to the port is never seen by the process running within the emulator.  It looks just like a firewall is active, blocking the outside access but I'm not aware that there is one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Rich

Comment: have you found any work around this?

Answer (score 0):

try to cold boot your emulator 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've done that.  I went as far as deleting all virtual devices and adding them back.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get around the problem.  There are multiple ways to setup the port redirection.  I was using the telnet process which wasn't working.  I switched over to the adb method and that works.  It's also easier - one command versus several.
The adb command is:

adb forward tcp:8090 tcp:8080

which forwards port 8090 on the host to port 8080 on the emulator.  This is the simple command when only one emulator is running.

I still have no idea why the telnet process doesn't work especially since it's the first method documented in google's web page on redirection.  Perhaps someone else can shed some light on this.
Rich